# rhombus lib is not working with Samsung Ace LaFleur(GT-S5830i) and Ace Duos(GT-S6802)

Tags: android, credit-card

We are using rhombus lib to read credit card data and have a problem with devices Samsung Ace LaFleur(GT-S5830i) and Ace Duos(GT-S6802) library is constantly registering false reads with zeroes (0000000) in read bits. How to fix this?